# "Keep All Records" not keeping all records

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins

Did ArcMap lose some functionality recently?

I am trying to join two tables to find which records don't have a match in the other. "Keep All Records" is selected in the join but it does not keep all records. It only keeps the ones there are matches for. I've done this hundreds of times and now it doesn't work. I have the same problem in ArcGIS Pro as well.

Does anyone know what is going on?

How can I work around this?

My two tables:
[image]

Join settings:

[image]

Resulting join:
[image]

Comment: Try Validate Join first (as it is possible  that there is a data issue)

Comment: Yep, This is what I get:
All field and datasource validation tasks were completed successfully.

"The number of matching records for the join:
- 898 of 1275 records matched by joining [Zip_num] from <VA_zipcodeLatLon_points> with [ZIP_CODE] from <Virginia_Zip_Codes>.
Matching records may not appear in table view due to join validation errors."

So...sure there are 898 joins. What are the 377 zip codes that didn't join? I used to be able to get that by doing this join but those records disappear even though I have "keep all records" set. Matching records are showing up.

Answer (score 1):

Through the ESRI Community forum, it was suggested that I try the "Add Join" geoprocessing tool. That worked perfectly.